# Unable to establish connection between Docker containers: Node application container cannot connect to MySQL container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I am trying to set up a multi-container application using the docker-compose concept.

The containers are creating and running successfully using `docker compose up -d` command

[image]

I can log in to MySQL Shell and it is displaying the database (named todos)-

[image]

### But the node app's logs are showing the connection error with MySQL

[image]

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file-

```
services:
  app:
    image: node:18-alpine
    command: sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DB: todos
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todos

volumes:
  todo-mysql-data:
```

Nodejs application is using this code to connect with MySQL-

```
const waitPort = require('wait-port');
const fs = require('fs');
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const {
    MYSQL_HOST: HOST,
    MYSQL_HOST_FILE: HOST_FILE,
    MYSQL_USER: USER,
    MYSQL_USER_FILE: USER_FILE,
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: PASSWORD,
    MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: PASSWORD_FILE,
    MYSQL_DB: DB,
    MYSQL_DB_FILE: DB_FILE,
} = process.env;

let pool;
async function init() {
    const host = HOST_FILE ? fs.readFileSync(HOST_FILE) : HOST;
    const user = USER_FILE ? fs.readFileSync(USER_FILE) : USER;
    const password = PASSWORD_FILE ? fs.readFileSync(PASSWORD_FILE) : PASSWORD;
    const database = DB_FILE ? fs.readFileSync(DB_FILE) : DB;

    await waitPort({ 
        host, 
        port: 3306,
        timeout: 10000,
        waitForDns: true,
    });

    pool = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit: 5,
        host,
        user,
        password,
        database,
        charset: 'utf8mb4',
    });

    return new Promise((acc, rej) => {
        pool.query(
            'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo_items (id varchar(36), name varchar(255), completed boolean) DEFAULT CHARSET utf8mb4',
            err => {
                if (err) return rej(err);

                console.log(`Connected to mysql db at host ${HOST}`);
                acc();
            },
        );
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help debug that?

**NOTE-**

If anyone wants to set up this demo, I am following the [docker documentation example](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/).

Comment: Looks like you simply need `depends_on: [mysql]`. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. I added the depends_on:
      - mysql but it is still not working.

Comment: It's done, edited.

Comment: Are you sure it's all there this time? I noticed you added in the `command` just now. Have you specified any `networks` by any chance?

Comment: What MySQL Node.js library are you using (name and version)?

Comment: I didn't add the network in the docker file. Docker is using the default network, "app_default" while creating the container. I inspect using docker commands and both containers are using the same network. I am adding the screenshots for more information.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to also show the connection code.

Comment: _"I am using mysql2"_... and the **version** is?

Comment: It's "mysql2": "^2.3.3",

Comment: I added the connection code as well.

Comment: That's an entire major version behind. I suggest you bump that up to 3.3.3

Comment: Try it without `waitPort` since that seems to be the cause of the issue

Comment: I tried running this application using proper docker commands (without docker-compose) and that worked well. (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/07_multi_container/) If version is an issue then it should happen with that case also. Please let me know if I am not correct.

Comment: "Try it without waitPort since that seems to be the cause of the issue" - It's still not working. If you can please setup this demo repository mentioned in the doc, (would hardly take less time if docker is installed). It would be great in debugging.

Comment: I have no problem. It says _"Waiting for mysql:3306..."_ then _"Connected!"_. Docker Compose version v2.17.2, Docker version 20.10.24, build 297e128 on MacOS 13.4

Comment: Oops!! Mines are- Docker version 23.0.5, build bc4487a, and Docker Compose version v2.17.3 on macOS Monetrey version 12.6.5.

Comment: I noticed a very strange thing. I made some changes in the connection code (just log the host and port), the server restarted and it got connected. It means the error was because of a timeout. What could be the fix to this problem?

Comment: Nothing. You already have redundancies to wait for the MySQL service to become available, `depends_on` and `waitFor`